# Euler's method for first three approximations?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[image]

I have tried variations of the problem for an hour at least and cannot get around to sloving this one.

Thank you for input!

Comment: Is it that you don't understand Euler's method at all? or is it that you understand Euler's method, but there's some specific thing about this particular problem that stops you from using Euler's method (and, if so, what is that specific thing)?

Comment: I honestly do not understand Eulers method at all

Comment: @Jerry Euler's method essentially gives you an approximate solution for a differential equation. Say there is a particular differential equation you can't solve exactly. Using euler's method, you find certain points at incremental distances from the intitial value, and try to make a polynomial fit to those values. That polynomial is the approximate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive Euler's method from Taylor series as

> $$ y(x_0+h)\approx y(x_0)+y'(x_0)h,\quad h=\Delta x.  $$

Put $x_1=x_0+h$ in the above equation which gives

> $$ y(x_1)\approx y(x_0)+y'(x_0)h,\quad h=\Delta x.  $$

If we repeat the process we get

> $$ y(x_2)=y(x_1+h)\approx y(x_1)+y'(x_1)h,\quad h=\Delta x , $$

which can be generalized to

> $$ y(x_n)=y(x_{n-1}+h)\approx y(x_{n-1})+y'(x_{n-1})h,\quad h=\Delta x \longrightarrow (*). $$

In your case, we will find $y(x_1)$ and you will do the rest. We have given the following information

> $$ x_0=0,\quad y(0)=5,\quad h=\Delta x = .1,\quad y'(x)=-7x^6e^{-x^7}\implies y'(0)=0. $$

Now substitute in

$$ y(x_1)=y(x_0+h)\approx y(x_0)+y'(x_0)h,\quad h=\Delta x  $$

gives

$$ y(x_1)=y(0+0.1)\approx y(0)+y'(0)(0.1),\quad h=\Delta x $$

> $$ y(x_1)=y(0.1) \approx 5 + 0 =5 \implies y(x_1)\approx 5. $$

To find $y(x_2)$ you need the following by checking the formula $(*)$

> $$ h=0.1,\quad x_1 = x_0 + h = 0.1,\quad y(x_1)\approx 5,\quad y'(x_1)=y'(0.1)=-7(0.1)^6e^{-(0.1)^7}.  $$

I think you can continue now.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's method is an iterative method using the linear approximation $y_{n+1}=y_n+h\cdot y'(x)$ where $h$ is the step size (given as $dx$ in the problem).

We have $y_0=5$, can you use the approximation to get $y_1$?

As for the exact case, that differential equation is separable.

Comment: okay so you plug 5 in for yn

Comment: And this is starting at $0$, so you plug in $0$ for $x$. So $y(0.1)$ is approximately what value?

Comment: its approximately h right?

Comment: Not quite, $y_1$ is $y(0.1)$ in this case, and $y'(0)=0$, so $y_1\approx y_0$. Do you see how the method works now?

Comment: yeah I kind of get it

Comment: Just keep using that approximation to get the next point, evaluating $y'(x)$ at each point.

Comment: okay thanks ill try my best on it!